# Scrapy xpath is not parsing what it should

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I have already tested the xpath and the tester result showed all the quotes that i wanted to extract but when I used the same xpath in scrapy it gives me the same quote over and over again. but when I remove "//" from xpath("//span[@class='text']/text()").get(), it gives me all the quotes that I want. I know // means find the element no matter where they are but // seems to be working fine with other elements during a for loop. For example : row.xpath('//span/small[@itemprop="author"]/text()').get()
the above do not give me the same Author name again and again like it does with the quotes. So, what seems to be the problem here?
[image: Tester results]
[image: Scrapy Results]

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['www.quotes.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print("response ------->", type(response))
        rows = response.\
            xpath("//div[@class='quote']")

        print("Quotes Count------>", len(rows))
        for row in rows:

            quote = row.\
                xpath("string(//span[@itemprop='text'])").get()

            yield {'quote': quote}

        print("Completed----------->>>>")
```

Comment: Please post your code as formated text instead of images. Makes it more readable and easier to help.

Comment: Hmm, I copied your exact code and ran it, and I got the correct result.

Comment: @FelixEklöf do it with //span in the xpath

Answer (score 0):

This spider, which is just likes yours except without some printing works for me.

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['www.quotes.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("//div[@class='quote']")

        for row in rows:
            quote = row.xpath("string(span[@itemprop='text'])").get()

            yield {'quote': quote}
```

Output

```
2021-03-10 09:51:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'quote': '“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”'}
2021-03-10 09:51:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'quote': '“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”'}
2021-03-10 09:51:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'quote': '“There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.”'}
...
```

**EDIT**
The [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths) have a good explanation. `//` will get all in the document, and not relative to your quote. Not sure why it works for author though.

Comment: sorry i accidently posted the code without "//span" in the xpath. run that again.

Comment: Then I get the same result as you. Use the code that I posted and It should work for you. I'm mostly use CSS selectors so I'm not sure why your code doesn't work.

Comment: also read the question please, the problem is not that i want the correct results, i already know how to get it but it does not make any sense that why using // give me the same result over and over again and why It does not do the same thing with other elements. For example if i use //span/small[@itemprop="author"]/text()  
to parse the author name it will not give me the same author name again and again like it does for quotes.

Comment: I added an edit. Maybe you've already read it. But maybe it's some help